Unable to build Expo project due to com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin not being found
I've recently been unable to run npx expo run:android for my react native Expo project (managed workflow) due to some errors.
Here is the error I'm being shown:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'helix'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:.
     Required by:
         project :
         project : > project :expo-updates-gradle-plugin
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
8 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 6 up-to-date

Here is my build.gradle file:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.23'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}

So far I've tried specifying specific versions and deleting android folder to rebuild, but they did not work.
Here is my package.json, in which I have @react-native/gradle-plugin installed:
{
  "name": "helix",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.18.11",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-native/gradle-plugin": "^0.76.3",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.46.1",
    "d3": "^7.9.0",
    "expo": "^51.0.38",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.28",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.27",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "zustand": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.8.1",
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

